# Partitioning an array into two arrays using special rule

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, partitioning

I've been working on the exercise and stumbled upon a problem.

Given an array of integers, determine whether or not it can be partitioned into two arrays, each of which is in increasing order. For instance 3,1,5,2,4 can, but 4,8,1,5,3 can't.

The problem is here. I couldn't understand why 1st array can but the 2nd one can't.
There is a hint given:
If we successfully partitioned an initial segment of the array, one of the parts must contain the maximum element seen so far. It is obviously in our best interest that the largest element of the other part be as small as possible. So, given the next element, if it's the maximum to this point add it to the "maximum containing part". If not there is no choice but to add it to the other part if possible (e.g: if it is larger than the largest element of this part, but it is not the current maximum). If this procedure fails then no partition is possible, and if it succeeds then we have demonstrated a partition.

The most important part is to understand the logic of this partitioning.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why it can't? Well, go ahead and try to partition 4,8,1,5,3 into two increasing sequences. That "hint" is basically just the algorithm.

Comment: Note that *any* sequence can be partitioned into `n` increasing sequences, for a sufficiently large `n`... the only question is, whether it's possible for some sequence and some `n`.

Comment: Do you need help seeing how the first can? Or why the second can't? Or why the algorithm is correct?

Comment: @Beta - yes It would be great if I can see how the first one partitions. Thank you

Comment: I think it would be considerably clearer if you also verified moving elements around is actually allowed, as well as the *results* of applying the aforementioned algorithm to the one that "works".

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't think that moving elements around (revising the partition of the partial sequence) is ever necessary; the algorithm minimizes the maxima of the two increasing series, and you can't do better than that.

Comment: @Beta Looking at your algorithm breakdown, I'm hard pressed to see how moving elements is avoidable if it indeed is *partitioning* as opposed to *is-partitionable*. I concur with your breakdown, btw. Its a good step-by-step and earned a +1. Tis probably my head being stuck in actual in-place partitioning functionality that sends me down that thought line, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I agree that *in-place* partitioning --by any algorithm-- requires moving elements. I thought 1) the OP meant more abstract partitioning, and 2) you meant backtracking. (It's interesting to note that for a sequence to be *unpartitionable* (in the sense of the question) it is necessary and sufficient that it contain {a,b,c} in order but not necessarily adjacent, such that a>b>c.)

Comment: @Beta yeah I noticed that sequence condition myself after reading your answer (which, again, is outstanding in how simply it describes the algorithm, thanks for making that so clear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the given algorithm on {3,1,5,2,4}.

First number is 3. Our partition is {3},{}.

Next comes 1. We can't add that to {3}, so we add it to the other: {3},{1}.

Next comes 5. We will add it to {3}, so as to save the {1} for smaller numbers: {3,5},{1}.

Next comes 2. we must add it to {1}: {3,5},{1,2}. (Now we see why it was good not to add 5 to {1}.)

Next comes 4: again, we have no choice: {3,5},{1,2,4}.